# Solving for the growth rate given a finite sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, linear-approximation

Given initial and final values, solving for an average growth rate over $n$ periods is trivial, however I'm interested in whether or not it's possible to solve for (or at least approximate) the growth rate given the number of periods and the *sum* of the values taken in each of the $n$ periods.

For instance, we know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (1+g)^{i-1} = \frac{1-(1+g)^n}{1-(1+g)}$$

and therefore if we want this to sum to some number, let's say $b$, then we have the equality

$$\frac{(1+g)^n-1}{g} = b$$

My question is, can you now approximate the $g$ that satisfies this? We of course assume $ g \approx 0$. It seems clear that finding a general analytical solution to this is impossible as it just expands into a higher degree polynomial, the roots of which need to be estimated numerically (as I understand it.) However, if there is a technique for this I'd love to hear it as it has an application to an Excel model I'm building and I'm in a bit of a bind with it.

Comment: I can continue but let me know if $g\ll 1$ as in finance calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function $$f(g)=(1+g)^n- b\,g+1$$ for which
$$f'(g)=n(1+g)^{n-1}-b \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(g)=n(n-1)(1+g)^{n-2}$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$g_*=\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}-1$$ So, for a first *approximation*, develop $f(g)$ as a Taylor series around $x_*$ to get
$$f(g)=f(g_*)+\frac 12 f''(g_*) (g-g_*)^2+O((g-g_*)^3)$$

So the first approximation could be
$$g_0=g_*+\sqrt{-2\frac{f(g_*)}{f''(g_*)}}$$ Using it for $n=20$ and $b=123456789$, this would give $g_0=1.805$ while the exact solution is $1.599$. Starting from this guess, Newton method will converge very fast as shown below.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & g_n \\
 0 & 1.80522 \\
 1 & 1.69723 \\
 2 & 1.62762 \\
 3 & 1.60177 \\
 4 & 1.59879 \\
 5 & 1.59875
\end{array}
\right)$$ We could make a better approximations using
$$g_0=g_*+3 \frac{f''(g_*)}{f'''(g_*)}\qquad g_0=g_*+\frac{4 f(g_*) f'''(g_*)}{f(g_*) f''''(g_*)-6 f''(g_*)^2}\qquad \cdots$$ For the worked example, these would respectively give $g_0=1.657$ and $g_0=1.587$.

**Specific case where $g \ll 1$**

This case corresponds to problems in finance. Consider now the original equation
$$b=\frac{(1+g)^n-1}{g}$$ and develop the rhs as a Taylor series built around $g=0$
$$b=n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} g  +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} g^2 +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24} g^3+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{120} g^4 +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)}{720} g^5 +O\left(g^6\right)$$

Using series reversion, this will give as an approximation
$$g=t-\frac{(n-2)}{3}  t^2+\frac{(n-2) (5 n-7)}{36}  t^3-\frac{(n-2) \left(17 n^2-44 n+29\right)}{270} t^4+\frac{(n-2) \left(193 n^3-708 n^2+885 n-374\right)}{6480}t^5+O\left(t^6\right)$$ where $t=\frac{2 (b-n)}{n(n-1)}$.

Let us try for $n=20$ and $b=25$. The above formula will give $g=0.022863$ while the exact solution is $0.022854$.

For sure, we could take more terms and have a better accuracy.

Comment: The exact solution of $g_0 = 1.599$ does not satisfy the assumption $g \ll 1$. In the question $b$ is the factor by which the sum on maturity exceeds the principal invested. Your choice of $b=123456789, n=20$ is unrealistic.

Comment: @sammygerbil. I precidely did not know of $g \ll 1$. See my question below the post. There is no the *finance* tag. This case will be treated now.

Comment: The only clue is "We of course assume g≈0."